# C++ chrono timers go 1000x slower in a thread

Tags: c++, timer, c++-chrono

My setup

- iOS13.2
- Xcode 11.2

I'm implementing a simple timer to count seconds by calendar/wall time.
From many SO tips, I tried various `std::chrono::` timers, such as

- `system_clock`
- `steady_clock`

They seem to behave correctly under a single-threaded program.
But in a production code, when I use the timer in a background thread, then it falls apart,

meaning that the duration readings from calling the timer functions are way off.

```cpp
m_thread = std::thread([&, this]() {

auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();  // a persistent state initialized at the beginning of the run.


while (true) {

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    auto isOutdated = duration > 1000;

    if (isOutdated) {
       print("we are outdated.").
    }

}
});
```

`duration` seems to be almost always 0;

`gettimeofday()` works slightly better, i.e. it actually moves, but at a rate 1000x slower than wall time.

I had thought that the `chrono` class counts all kinds of times, but it seems that I have the wrong expectation how it works.

What am I missing?

### UPDATE

Forgot to say, I have 2 more threads going at the same time. Could thread preemption affect this?

### UPDATE 2

I tried a few things and now the program behaves as expected, but this actually drove me mad how it happened in the first place.

Things I did

- Gradually increase the timeout threshold from 1 to 3000, each time the whole program gets recompiled. I found that when I lower the threshold, the program actually gets the duration right.
- Try with `gettimeofday()` first, which consistently shows numbers 1000x slower, then switch back to `system_clock`.
- Disable some logging to avoid performance hit. I use a thirdparty thread-safe logging lib, which writes to a log file and outputs to device syslog at the same time.

Right now I can finally see the correct duration. NO change in the code logic. What a bizarre experience!

Comment: there is nothing in between your start and stop time, why did you expect anything else than `0` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 there is. I haven't found a way to express this in pseudo code. Basically `s_start` is a state initialized way earlier.

Comment: the thing is, if you dont show the code we cannot know why you measure the time difference that you measure

Comment: it isnt that unlikely that what you think takes > 1ms in fact does not. 1ms is quite a long time for a cpu

Comment: If it's just setting a variable maybe the compiler has optimized it away in release mode to some previous location, or the executed code really is just short and fast? If you provide a minimal example for reproduction that'd be great.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I just updated my question. This looks more like how it happens.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt This is under Debug.

Comment: now I dont understand it anymore, `duration` should monotonically increase until it is `>1000` which should happen after roughly 1second. Now your claim that it is "almost always 0" is a bit odd

Comment: It might be worthwhile to watch your app inside Activity Monitor, in particular the "App Nap" column, to see if MacOS/X is playing with your timers' accuracy as a way to save power.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I tried a different phone and it moves with chrono, but still like 1000 times slower. This is not OS X, but logging through syslog on the phones.

Comment: A millisecond is a long time on a modern computer.  You might try a finer precision.  On iOS the precision of `system_clock` is microseconds, and the precision of `steady_clock` is nanoseconds.

Comment: You'll most probably get the result from one thread many many times before it switches to the next thread and then you'll get a lot of results from that thread and so on - 1 ms won't be noticed often. Try increasing the resolution. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a324258208dac46e

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks! This helps.

Comment: You should maybe prefer `std::chrono::steady_clock` for timing like this. Especially if you expect this code to be correct during a change to the wall clock like a DST shift, for example :)